# UIButton Design Tools

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibutton

I want to design a UIButton in a specific way and cannot find in the Interface Builder all the relevant tools required for the design.

The tools I cannot find:

- **Text Alignment**: I want to have the text aligned to the middle (it is available for UILabel, but I don't see this option in UIButton).
- **Button Edges**: I want to use **Type >> Custom** so I can have control over the button color and opacity; still, I wish to have rounded edges (like the **Type >> Rounded Rect** has). How can I do that?
- **Edges Style/Design**: If/Once I have these rounded edges for the button, I wish to set the width of the edges and its color (to have this nice frame). Is it possible?

If I can do it via Interface Builder, I prefer that; I don't mind setting these attributes via code as well...

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You couldn't set that properties via Interface Builder. You set them in code.

Comment: Here's a good way to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that level of customizability you'll have to make a custom button and either draw it in code or use images. Things like corner radius and edge style are not customizable in interface builder.