# Is it possible to set UIView border properties from interface builder?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, border

Is it possible to control UIView border properties (color, thickness, etc...) directly from interface builder or I can only do it programmatically?

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/28854514/3177007](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28854514/3177007)

Comment: Just in case anyone comes from Google like I did. To see those changes reflect in IB you just need to create a subclass of UIView and assign it to whatever View you want to manipulate in IB.

Answer (score 405, accepted):

Actually you can set some properties of a view's layer through interface builder. I know that I can set a layer's borderWidth and cornerRadius through xcode. borderColor doesn't work, probably because the layer wants a CGColor instead of a UIColor.

You might have to use Strings instead of numbers, but it works!

```
layer.cornerRadius
layer.borderWidth
layer.borderColor
```

> Update:
>   layer.masksToBounds = true

[image: example]

> Update:
>   select appropriate Type for Keypath:
>  [image]

Comment: To you and Peter DeWeese: I use Xcode 4.6.3 and I can set keypath type to "Color" without impleting a CALayer interface

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! They must have fixed that in a newer version of xcode than I had at the time

Comment: Unfortunately layer.borderColor can't be set this way.  It's a CGColorRef, but that IB Color value type is a UIColor.

Comment: Make sure you have included the QuartzCore framework or it won't work.

Comment: So THIS is what the user defined runtime attributes does! Haha, been writing for iOS since 2011 and I never learned what those fields were for. Thanks for this awesome answer.

Comment: layer.borderColor does not seem to work in IB (Xcode 6).  Again guessing that its because its a UIColor not a CGColor.

Comment: Number types for cornerRadius, borderWidth works fine. layer.borderColor does not work because it is not CGColor.

Comment: Here is my solution from within IB in storyboard, all working (even Color) :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/29074130

Comment: Nice, but you have to set the correct type for each property. The Type for e. g. "layer.cornerRadius" has to be set to "Number" instead of "String"!

Comment: If it does not work, make sure you don't have `layer.borderColor` or `borderColor` under `User Defined Runtime Attributes`

Comment: I came here looking for why my corners wouldn't bend, only to find out I had misspelled `cornerRadius` in the inspector :)

Comment: Hi everyone - just wanted to point out that this answer is only valid in conjunction with the answer from @Peter DeWeese

Comment: Also, don't forget to check the "clip to bounds" checkbox to have the cornerRadius working.

Comment: Should be `layer.borderUIColor`

Answer (score 191):

Rich86Man's answer is correct, but you can use categories to proxy properties such as layer.borderColor. (From the [ConventionalC](https://github.com/ConventionalC/ConventionalC/blob/develop/ios/CALayer+XibConfiguration.h) CocoaPod)

**CALayer+XibConfiguration.h:**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CALayer(XibConfiguration)

// This assigns a CGColor to borderColor.
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIColor* borderUIColor;

@end
```

**CALayer+XibConfiguration.m:**

```
#import "CALayer+XibConfiguration.h"

@implementation CALayer(XibConfiguration)

-(void)setBorderUIColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

-(UIColor*)borderUIColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.borderColor];
}

@end
```

[image: Interface Builder]

```
layer.borderUIColor
```

The result will be apparent during runtime, not in Xcode.

**Edit**: You also need to set `layer.borderWidth` to at least 1 to see the border with the chosen color.

***In Swift 2.0:***

```
extension CALayer {
    @objc var borderUIColor: UIColor {
        set {
            self.borderColor = newValue.CGColor
        }
    
        get {
            return UIColor(CGColor: self.borderColor!)
        }
    }
}
```

***In Swift 3.0:***

```
extension CALayer {
    @objc var borderUIColor: UIColor {
        set {
            self.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
        }
    
        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: self.borderColor!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. The .m file moans about borderColor having to be borderUIColor and to fix it, after doing so it still shows warnings and the border color doesnt render at runtime. The bit that is different on mine is I have @ implementation NameOfFile, not @ implementation CALayer(NameOfFile), I dont understand the CALayer part, could you explain that more please

Comment: CALayer(myCategory) is a category, that is, it adds its methods to an existing class that is implemented elsewhere. In this case CALayer is included with the framework and I am just adding the borderUIColor property to it. Your way of implementing this will not work, although I suppose that you could add the property to your view controller and have it update the layer instead.

Comment: To get it work you should set borderWidth type to String, not Number. Pretty confusing.

Comment: You actually can use Number with borderWidth and accept an NSNumber. It works fine.

Comment: We cannot add variable in category. I am not getting how this whole thing is working? Can you please explain, I am confused?

Comment: @Nuzhat Zari, The variable already exists in CALayer, and this is simply adding a wrapper around it. No variable is created by the category!

Comment: I have applied layer.borderUIColor in User defined runtime attributes...it's not working in  runtime also.

Comment: @Singapore, try setting breakpoints in your category methods to make sure it is calling them. As a note, you can simply proxy it from UIView instead of CALayer.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution in my opinion to solve the issue of BorderColor. Fantastic use of categories!

Comment: If anyone's wondering about the Swift solutions, it works!
01. Create a Cocoa Touch Class file: UIButton.
02. Associate the IB Button with your newly created class in IB.
03. Add the extension to the newly created class (above code).

Comment: Worked in Swift !

Comment: In case if swift doesn't work for someone, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554726/618994

Answer (score 95):

*Similar answer to iHulk's one, but in Swift*

Add a file named UIView.swift in your project (or just paste this in any file) :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
        get {
            guard let color = layer.borderColor else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            clipsToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Then this will be available in Interface Builder for every button, imageView, label, etc. in the Utilities Panel > Attributes Inspector :

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Note: the border will only appear at runtime.

Comment: @Gaurav What error do you see ? On which component (UIButton, UILabel, etc.) are you using it ?

Comment: I can't help you without more details :(

Comment: can you explain problem in this code :

   @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
               return UIColor(CGColor: color)
           }
           return nil
        }
        set(newValue) {
           layer.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor
       }
    }

Comment: You are not making it easy for me, this code is a simple getter/setter and works fine with xCode 7.2.1. (Swift 2.1 if I'm not mistaken) Maybe you use a different version of Swift ? What error do you experience ? I can't guess ...

Comment: please check may last comment . i have post my code can you please explain my mistake

Comment: I was getting Interface Builder crashes with this approach until I removed `@IBDesignable` from the beginning of the extension.

Comment: That is amazing...  Thanks!    I'm using XCode 8.2.1

Comment: Very handy and neat! Thanks!

Comment: I would add that `newValue!.CGColor` should be `newValue!.cgColor` now.

Comment: @AndrewWhite Yes, I updated my answer with the Swift 3 syntax. Thank you !

Comment: I added the code and got the settings in the attribute inspector. but when i select a border colour and run the app there is no error but the border colour does not change. I have created a separate file to add the above swift 3 code.

Comment: @AxelGuilmin is there anything I can do in adaptive layout for corner radius?

Comment: @MihirOza no idea sorry

Answer (score 58):

You can make a category of UIView and add this in .h file of category

```
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *borderColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;
```

Now add this in .m file

```
@dynamic borderColor,borderWidth,cornerRadius;
```

and this as well in . m file

```
-(void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor{
    [self.layer setBorderColor:borderColor.CGColor];
}

-(void)setBorderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth{
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
}

-(void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius{
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:cornerRadius];
}
```

now you will see this in your storyboard for all UIView subclasses (UILabel, UITextField, UIImageView etc)

[image]

Thats it.. No Need to import category anywhere, just add the category's files in the project and see these properties in the storyboard.

Comment: Complement it with IB_DESIGNABLE to make IB redraw your custom view using the drawRect: method  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014224-CH41-SW1

Comment: Thats great, If you write IB_DESIGNABLE in the .h file before the interface line, you dont need to add @dynamic line in .m

Comment: @user1618612 it has nothing to do with the resolution, it is just setting normal layer properties.

Answer (score 13):

For **Swift 3 and 4**, if you're willing to use `IBInspectable`s, there's this:

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue!.cgColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth:CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius:CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            clipsToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a best solution for me

Comment: Great Solution , Thank u

Answer (score 7):

while this might set the properties, it doesnt actually reflect in IB. So if you're essentially writing code in IB, you might as well then do it in your source code

Comment: Welcome to MVC! You view properties should **never** be in code!

Comment: ^ This is not what MVC is.

Comment: Considering that 95% of the time this code goes in the controller, it is also MVC, of course should you properly subclass or extend your view then its just configuration over coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its absolutely possible only when you set `layer.masksToBounds = true` and do you  rest stuff.

Answer (score -1):

> Storyboard doesn't work for me all the time even after trying all the
>   solution here

So it is always perfect answer is using the code, Just create IBOutlet instance of the UIView and add the properties

*Short answer :*

```
layer.cornerRadius = 10
layer.borderWidth = 1
layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

---

*Long answer :*

### Rounded Corners of UIView/UIButton etc

```
customUIView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

### Border Thickness

```
pcustomUIView.layer.borderWidth = 2
```

### Border Color

```
customUIView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

Comment: The question is very specific and ask how to do it from the Interface Builder. Your answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score -5):

Please add these 2 simple line of code:

```
self.YourViewName.layer.cornerRadius = 15
self.YourViewName.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

It will work fine.