# Set a border for UIButton in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, storyboard

I can't get a border onto my buttons in Xcode 5 without setting them directly in the code. Is it possible that there's no way to do this on the storyboard without making a custom background image?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use key path.

For example the corner radius (`layer.cornerRadius`) as describe on the image.
<s>You will not be able to see the effects on storyboard, cause this parameters are evaluated at runtime.</s> Now you can use a swift category in UIView (code bellow the picture) in with `@IBInspectable` to show the result at the storyboard (If you are using the category, use only `cornerRadius` and not `layer.cornerRadius` as a key path.

[image]

---

```
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is category from [Peter DeWeese](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993890/1107651) answer that allow use keypath `layer.borderUIColor` to set the border color.

CALayer+XibConfiguration.h:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CALayer(XibConfiguration)

// This assigns a CGColor to borderColor.
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIColor* borderUIColor;

@end
```

CALayer+XibConfiguration.m:

```
#import "CALayer+XibConfiguration.h"

@implementation CALayer(XibConfiguration)

-(void)setBorderUIColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

-(UIColor*)borderUIColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.borderColor];
}

@end
```

Comment: You learn something new every day.. this would have been useful to know many months ago hah.

Comment: Wow, this is so cool! I didn't know about this hidden gem! Upvoted.

Comment: BTW, I also had to set `layer.borderWidth` for the border to show.

Comment: That is wild! Thanks so much Guilherme, and I have a feeling that's going to come in handy in the future

Comment: Can I set the layer.borderColor? That doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: It's because layer.boderColor expected a CGColor, not an UIColor. But you can make a category as workaround. wait a minute, i will update my answer

Comment: Magic! Wow, so the nomenclature of CALayer+XibConfiguration makes it configure layers in XibConfigurations? It worked for me but I don't understand how! Anyway, thank you so much Guilherme. Great answer.

Comment: My LAST question, if you have a second, is would any of this allow for just adding a top border, or just a left border, etc. If not I see some workarounds I can try, but just curious - it's not critical to what I'm doing, I just feel like this is going to be a popular q/a so if it could be more complete and you already know how to do it, why not add it?

Comment: Tommy, I will update my answer with a workaround for this, but i don't have time to test right now

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro I'm a little new to iOS development. Are border color snippets in a separate file? How do you use it once implemented?

Comment: Yes @NoahPassalacqua, It's a category (search for it in google, to get some explanation on this). Once you have added the category to your project you can use: layer.borderUIColor keypath at interface builder.

Comment: There is only a slight problem with this approach. When a modal view is presented, the border color of the button doesn't change. It looks weird with other standard controls like a segmented control which gray out when a modal view is presented. Because of this, I'm using a subclass of UIButton. However, when a view is presented, I'm unable to detect it and change the border color to gray. Bummer...

Comment: I just tried it and am not seeing the changes in the rounder corners show in my storyboard. However, I do see the changes when running the file. I'm on 6.3.2. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MatthewChung to see the changes in IB you have to make a category the UIView , and not for the CALayer. Which one did you used ?

Comment: Thanks for writing @GuilhermeTorresCastro . I am using the swift extension. I know this is probably asking too much, but i made a trivial project with 1 view and the extension and it is still not displaying rounded corners in the storyboard. If you have 2 minutes, it would be very very much appreciated. https://github.com/captainchung/test

Comment: It would be worthwhile also showing a screen shot of the addition UI element that appears once you've a swift extension in place, so it does not have to be done in the user defined values area.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3**
If you want to see the result in IB when you use IBInspectable, you have to extend UIView and add the properties to that class, i.e.

```
@IBDesignable class MyView: UIView {}

extension MyView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return UIColor.init(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

reference: http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer :*

```
layer.cornerRadius = 10
layer.borderWidth = 1
layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

---

*Long answer :*

### Rounded Corners UIButton

```
customUIView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

### Border Thickness

```
pcustomUIView.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

### Border Color

```
customUIView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set your UIButton User Defined Run Time Attributes ie
borderWidth, cornerRadius, borderColor etc. As shown in the image.
Note:- don't use layer. before the attribute name, it will not work.

[image]

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work, can you provide a link to documentation why this should work? or an example. I guess you mean you need first write extension with IBInspectable vars like in other answers. Answer need to be full

Answer (score 0):

[It is correct! See Key "borderColor" - this is without "layer."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC50N.png)

Comment: This is already in @Muhammad‘s answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a piece of code like:

`self.addButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];`

Please note: `addButton` is an IBOutlet.

Comment: Questioner needs non-programing way.