# Create a circle in xib for interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, core-graphics

I've been drawing my circles using Core Graphics, but I have recently started implementing xibs using the interface builder for my views. Is there anyway to draw a circle using the interface builder? Surprisingly, I couldn't find any other thread answering this question even though it sounds like a simple one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't per-se, but you can achieve this effect using a view's corner radius. This is performance-heavy however, so you should test on different devices and see the performance implications of this.

Xcode provides a "User Defined Runtime Attributes" section:

[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes]

The format of this is key path and value.

You could set the `layer.cornerRadius` keypath to half the width/height of the view. To help with performance, you can set the `layer.shouldRasterize` key path to `YES`.

Comment: That's nifty. However it's not showing the circle in the interface builder

Comment: No, it won't. Notice how the section is called "Runtime Attributes". These values are applied after decoding the view from the nib during runtime.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Is there an option for changing the color and alpha of the corners of the button?

Comment: The layer has a `borderColor` property, but this you can only change in code, because it requires a `CGColor` object rather than `UIColor`.

Comment: I actually found a way to change it using interface builder, check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder/17993890#17993890