# Set UIView BorderColor in IB for Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to set runtime attributes `layer.borderColor` in swift (for a prototype tableview)

However, the color setting does not actually set the UIColor as pointed out in a bunch of answers. Is there a swift implementation of this:

[Is it possible to set UIView border properties from interface builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder/17993890#17993890)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to proxy the value to set it as a CGColor. I [answered the question you mentioned for Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder/17993890#17993890), and now here it is in swift.

```
extension UIView
{
    var borderColor: UIColor {
        set{ self.layer.borderColor = newValue.CGColor }
        get{ return UIColor(CGColor: self.layer.borderColor!) }
    }
}
```