# Change UIButton BorderColor in Storyboard

Tags: ios, colors, uibutton, storyboard

I Set CornerRadius and BorderWidth for UIbutton in User Defined Runtime Attributes. Without adding **layer.borderColor** it works Well and Display border in black color. But when add **layer.borderColor** does not work(does not show border).

[image]

Answer (score 163, accepted):

**For Swift:**

[image]

**Swift 3:**

```
extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 2.2:**

```
extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return UIColor(CGColor: layer.borderColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, however XCode(Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)) doesn't show result in preview, is this right and no way to change(except creating custom view)?

Comment: I know this answer is old (and great by the way), but I need to ask if this would affect the compiling time or something like that? adding this to all the UIView?

Comment: @Vertig0 adding what to the UIView? 3 properties? Absolutely not.

Answer (score 98):

I got answer. Change  **borderColor** instead of **layer.borderColor**:

[image: Xcode snippet]

and add this code in .m file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@implementation CALayer (Additions)

- (void)setBorderColorFromUIColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

@end
```

**Tick** properties in Attribute Inspector

[image: Attribute Inspector]

Comment: @jithin I wrote it as a Swift extension, here's the code:

extension CALayer {
  func setBorderColorFromUIColor(color: UIColor) {
    self.borderColor = color.CGColor
  }
}

Comment: trick worked. partially. how on earth am I getting black border color even though i specified red color?!!!!!! any ideas? anyone?

Comment: @static0886: It was because of what color you're applying is not set to the border. As per my understanding we can't set border color from storyboard as this property won't get reflected in the UIComponent at runtime.  By default it is black color. If you want give a trial by removing the color property from Attributes.

Comment: For swift you can set it as:  
self.button.layer.borderColor = <UIColor.CGColor>

Comment: That  layer.borderColorFromUIColor worked for me in the story board. Thank you.

Comment: hello  i am create CustomeView class in objective c but its not showing in my storyboard Plz help me.

Answer (score 59):

**Swift 4, Xcode 9.2** - Use `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable` to build custom controls and live preview the design in Interface Builder.

Here is a sample code in Swift, place just below the `UIKit` in ViewController.swift:

```
@IBDesignable extension UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            guard let uiColor = newValue else { return }
            layer.borderColor = uiColor.cgColor
        }
        get {
            guard let color = layer.borderColor else { return nil }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }
}
```

If you go to the Attributes inspectable of the view, you should find these properties visually, edit the properties:

[image]

The changes are also reflected in User Defined Runtime Attributes:

[image]

Run in build time and Voila! you will see your clear rounded button with border.

[image]

Comment: This helped me to achieve it in storyboard. Your answer is very clear to implement.

Comment: This is the most precise answer for this question with clearly explained example.

Comment: If you could add for Objective-C, it will be appreciated.

Comment: This is the best answer I've found till date.

Answer (score 9):

The explanation, perhaps being lost in some of the other answers here:

The reason that this property is not being set is that `layer.borderColor` needs a value with type `CGColor`.

But only `UIColor` types can be set via Interface Builder's User Defined Runtime Attributes!

So, you must set a UIColor to a proxy property via Interface Builder, then intercept that call to set the equivalent CGColor to the `layer.borderColor` property.

This can be accomplished by creating a Category on CALayer, setting the Key Path to a unique new "property" (`borderColorFromUIColor`), and in the category overriding the corresponding setter (`setBorderColorFromUIColor:`).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

Swift 3, Xcode 8.3

[image: Identity inspector (UIButton in this case]

CALayer extension:

```
extension CALayer {
var borderWidthIB: NSNumber {
    get {
        return NSNumber(value: Float(borderWidth))
    }
    set {
        borderWidth = CGFloat(newValue.floatValue)
    }
}
var borderColorIB: UIColor? {
    get {
        return borderColor != nil ? UIColor(cgColor: borderColor!) : nil
    }
    set {
        borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
}
var cornerRadiusIB: NSNumber {
    get {
        return NSNumber(value: Float(cornerRadius))
    }
    set {
        cornerRadius = CGFloat(newValue.floatValue)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way to do this!  You should use @IBInspectable.  Check out Mike Woelmer's blog entry here:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/07/18/swift-interface-builder/

It actually adds the feature to IB in Xcode!  Some of the screenshots in other answers make it appear as though the fields exist in IB, but at least in Xcode 9 they do not.  But following his post will add them.

Comment: I tried this approach and it made Xcode really slow. Is it happening to you all as well?

Answer (score 0):

In case of Swift, function doesn't work. You'll need a computed property to achieve the desired result:

```
extension CALayer {
    var borderColorFromUIColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return UIColor(CGColor: self.borderColor!)
        } set {
            self.borderColor = newValue.CGColor
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have set the data values for the radius and the width set to be a string, but it should properly be to be set to a number, not a string

When you get it working, this will not be visible while looking at the storyboard, but will be when the app is running unless you have taken steps to make it @IBDesigneable.