# How to change border color on button?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I change the border color of a button?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48470255/8014650

Comment: yourButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
yourButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CALayer. Every UIView has a ‘layer’ property on which you can set a borderWidth, color, etc...

Comment: Can i get a code example please? like where in the viewcontroller.swift do i add that code? :S?

Comment: See Andrei’s answer

Answer (score 0):

Put inside your `viewDidLoad` method inside ViewController:

```
yourButtonProperty.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Replace `yourButtonProperty` with property for your Button. 
Docs for CALayer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer

Comment: Can i get a code example please? like where in the viewcontroller.swift do i add that code? :S?