# Add Rounded corners after resizing UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Facing problem when adding rounded corners to imageview. 
here is my code

```
CALayer * lay = [imageview layer];
[lay setMasksToBounds:YES];
[lay setCornerRadius:10.0];

[lay setBorderWidth:5.0];
[lay setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];

imageview.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
imageview.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

And its working fine but if I am resizing the `imageview`, its not making corners round.

Here is my resizing code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^ {
    [imageview setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)];

    CALayer * l = [imageview layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:10.0];

    [l setBorderWidth:5.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];

    imageview.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    imageview.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

    newimage = imageview.image;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newimage,1.1) forKey:@"newimage"];   

}];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note : Corner radius is not animatable in animateWithDuration:animations:, so add your functions in outside the block and try , it will work

Comment: ok i'll be doing it.

Comment: Do you want animate the corner radius and also re-size the image at the same time?What your objective to re size or corner radius imageview?

Comment: Your code is working fine. I am able to resize it  along with rounded corners.

Comment: newimage = imageview.image; Here do you expect your newimage to have rounded corners?

Comment: hi @SahanaKini  yes newimage  should be resized.

Comment: imageview.image would return you the image you have initially set. It will not return image with rounded corner.

Comment: Are you telling that  newimage does not have corner radius?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set corner radius from storyboard or XIB hope it will work, Please check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder).

Comment: i tried your solution, at first its working fine but after re sizing rounded corners went off.

Answer (score 0):

Plz import the QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

and then write the code ...

yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourRadius;

yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Why to write the clipsToBounds property

A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the bounds of the view.

Discussion
Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is NO.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^
     {
        [imageview setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [imageview.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
         imageview.clipsToBounds = YES;
         imageview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
         [imageview.layer setBorderWidth:5.0];
         [imageview.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
         newimage = imageview.image;

         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newimage,1.1) forKey:@"newimage"];
     }];
```

You have to round corners after animation complete. You may get animation completion as above.

Comment: hey i tried your code but its not making corners round.