# Exclusive touch on UIControl

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an `UIButton` and `UISwitch`. A user could touch both with one finger each at the same time and release - triggering 2 separate `TouchUpInside` `@IBAction`s.

How can I tell a control that it's touches must be exclusive, without creating a subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIControl is subclass of UIView so you can directly set **exclusiveTouch = true** on any UI control.

Comment: Can this be set in IB? `Multiple Touch` is unchecked.

Comment: Sure. Take a look at this unswear for hint how to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder