# Can't make User Defined Runtime Attributes work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xcode-storyboard

I would really like to be able to use the "User Defined Runtime Attributes " from xcode Storyboard to build a nice pop up through a container view.
Unfortunately, I can't make it works and can't figure out why !

I found many topics (eg: [Is it possible to set UIView border properties from interface builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder)) which deal about it but this doesn't work for me... !

Here is the attribute inspector of the containerView embed UIView (I also tried to implement into containerView UIView too with no success).

[image]

I added an extension to transform UIColor to CGColor as expected :

```
extension CALayer {
var borderUIColor: UIColor {
    set {
        self.borderColor = newValue.CGColor
    }

    get {
        return UIColor(CGColor: self.borderColor!)
    }
}
```

}

Does someone could think about something missing ?

Thank you very much in advance ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `layer.borderColor`, use `layer.borderUIColor` in your user defined runtime attributes. Just double click the key name and add `UI`.

Comment: Yep that's it ! Thank you very much :) !