# Xcode 9 borderColor doesn't work in User Defined Runtime Attributes

Tags: ios, calayer, ios11, xcode9-beta, xcode9

I'm using this `CALayer` extension:

```
var borderUIColor: UIColor {
    set {
        self.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
    }

    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: self.borderColor!)
    }
}
```

I thought that maybe because of this extension my `borderColor` of the Submit button from the bottom of the page doesn't change to white (as I want it to be):

[image]

But no, I hooked up an `IBOutlet` and tried to set directly the color like this:

```
submitButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Did it in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` because I know that in the last big update (iOS 10) the frame rendering was changed fundamentally (the 1000x1000 frame thing) and maybe there were some similar alterations now. No luck, though.

I tested in iOS 9, 10 and 11. It's not about the OS, rather about the environment. I'm using Xcode 9 Beta 5. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: How did you verify that it's just an Xcode 9 issue?

Comment: Try self.submitButton.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: @meaning-matters the same code run in Xcode 8 works perfectly.

Comment: @iParesh thank you for the tip but the color is still black.

Comment: Have you given the `borderWidth`?

Comment: @KusalShrestha Yes, I have. Otherwise the border wouldn't be black at all, it would be invisible. Check out my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try decorating your var declaration with `@objc` like so:

```
@objc var borderUIColor: UIColor {
...
}
```

that should fix your problem

Answer (score 5):

Cleared the project, deleted the derived data and the code works now, in either `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

The issue is apparently with the **User Defined Runtime Attributes**. Xcode 9 no longer accepts extension vars here. Or, at least, the Beta 5 version.

EDIT: Indeed, adding `@objc` solves the issue.

Comment: Adding @objc to the variable declaration fixes the problem even if it is declared in extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue, and got another solution: I just made my class KVC-compliant.

Sample, step-by-step:

- Custom class is XTCMenuItem, with property propIdentifier.
- For KVC-compliance, this class got the two methods:

  - override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any?
  - override func setValue(_ value:
    Any?, forKey key: String)
- In Identity Inspector, I set custom class
  to "XTCMenuItem", and add the user defined runtime attribute
  "propIdentifier" with type "String", and a string value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create IBOutlet and just use RunTime Attributes, then you can use IBDesignable and set prefix @objc it will solve your problem.

```
@objc @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor {

   get {
      return UIColor(cgColor: self.layer.borderColor!)
   }
   set {
      self.layer.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use @IBInspectable attribute.
Example:

```
@IBInspectable var borderColor = UIColor.green
```