# Runtime BorderColor is not working in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made a extension of CALayer for border color as a runtime attribute, but it is not working.

It shows default black color only.

```
extension CALayer {
    var borderUIColor: UIColor {
        set {
            self.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
        }

        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: self.borderColor!)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need no extension. You can access layer's `borderColor` from Xcode's _Identity Inspector_ directly.

Comment: There is no such kind of functionality, I think.

Comment: @macmoonshine : I guess u can specify layer.borderColor in user defined runtime attributes section

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, but it shows only black color border

Comment: @nirav: Sorry, you're right. See my answer.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari: Yes, I know. This section is contained in Xcode's Identity Inspector as I stated.

Comment: @nirav do you get any workaround?

Comment: this may help you, i fixed issue with this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554726/6831708

Answer (score 1):

You should handle `nil` values with care, and may create an extension to `UIView` which declares the property as `@IBInspectabe`:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set { layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor }
    }
}
```

This makes it much easier to set the border color in Attribute Inspector.

EDIT: Your example works for me with Xcode 9.0 and 8.3.3 as well. Probably it was a bug in a beta version.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question about why their solution isn’t working.

Comment: @BryanBryce: Sorry, I couldn't give a more detailed reason last week. I think this was an issue in a beta version of Xcode. The extension of _nirav_ works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension UILabel{
    func setBorderColor(width:CGFloat,color:UIColor) -> Void
    {
        self.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = width
    }
}
```

and implement this function wherever you want,like this

```
label.setBorderColor(width: 2.0, color: UIColor.brown)
```

Hope this helps!