# Unable to set border on UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have tried so many times to just get a simple border on an ImageView but nothing seems to work. Those are my active settings now:

[image: Settings]

But the result is still without any border.

[image: No border]

What am I missing in my settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layer.borderColor` is a `CGColorRef`. But interface builder passes a `UIColor`. You have two options:

1 - Set the border color in code:

```
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

2 - Extend `UIImageView` or `UIView` with a `borderColor` property and use `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`so that property is visible in interface builder. Use this new property as a proxy to `layer.borderColor`.

```
@IBDesignable
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let cgColor = self.layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: cgColor)
            }
            return nil
        } set {
            self.layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

Related Posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993890/3814799

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35372610/3814799

Comment: You can't return nil since your variable is not optional.

Comment: You are still wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot the ?. Fixed.

Comment: @ElTomato - then this looks like a perfect opportunity for you to correct me

Comment: newValue is also optional since you have made borderColor optional.

Comment: fixed again. Next time I'll write my code in Xcode beforehand :)